# On Matplotlib, how do i move my legend where I want it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How would I move my legend to inside the graph right under where my title is?

```
plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4], color='r', label="Apple")
plt.plot([3, 4], [5, 6], color='g', label="Pear")
plt.title("Total Profit Trend by Month")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `plt.legend(loc='upper left')` or you can replace 'upper left' by the following locations:

upper right,
lower left,
lower right,
right,
center left,
center right,
lower center,
upper center,
center.